# lead conversion trigger causing issue when multiple lead records are inserted

Tags: apex, trigger

I wrote a trigger that will create records in multiple objects and then converts it but when I insert multiple records then its showing below error.

> ContactCreationFromLead: execution of BeforeUpdate
>   caused by: System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 3

Basically my requirement is, On lead object I have two sections Student detail(Standard lead Fields) and parent details(create custom field like Fname, Lname and Email). So once Parent_or_guardian__c = true then I need to create two Contacts for student and parent, then I need to catch those two contact ids then create a record in hed_Relationship object where hed__Contact__c = studentcontactId and hed__RelatedContact__c = parent Id, for one record its working perfectly

My trigger is below.

```
trigger ContactCreationFromLead on Lead(After insert, before Update) {
    //trigger to create contact, relationship, affiliation records from lead.
    List < Lead > em = new List < Lead > ();
    List < Contact > conInsertList = new List < Contact > ();
    List < hed__Affiliation__c > affiliation = new List < hed__Affiliation__c > ();
    List < hed__Relationship__c > relation = new List < hed__Relationship__c > ();
    List < hed__Affiliation__c > affiliationListToBeInserted = new List < hed__Affiliation__c > ();
    List < String > listEmail = new List < String > ();
    List < String > listname = new List < String > ();
    Set < String > otherProgramsValueSet = new Set < String > ();
    if (trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate) {
        for (Lead em: Trigger.new) {
            if (em.Email != null) {
                listEmail.add(em.Email);
            }
            if (em.What_is_your_primary_program_of_interest__c != null) {
                listname.add(em.What_is_your_primary_program_of_interest__c);
            }
            if (em.Other_Programs_of_Interest__c != null) {
                otherProgramsValueSet.addAll(em.Other_Programs_of_Interest__c.split(';'));
            }
        }
    }
    //to catch the account Id that matches the lead primary program of interest
    //account name should match with primary program of interest picklist values
    List < Account > account = [SELECT Id, Name, Pardot_Program_Name__c from Account WHERE Pardot_Program_Name__c =: listname];
    string record;
    for (Account acc: account) {
        record = acc.Id;
    }
    List < Contact > cem = [SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE Email =: listEmail];
    String cemail;
    for (Contact ce: cem) {
        cemail = ce.Email;
    }
    Id recordtype1 = [select Id From RecordType WHERE DeveloperName = 'Lead'].Id;
    Id recordtype2 = [select Id From RecordType WHERE DeveloperName = 'Parent'].Id;
    //code to create contact for student if form is filled by student
    for (Lead ld: Trigger.new) {
        if (ld.Email != cemail && ld.Parent_or_guardian__c == false) {

            Contact cnt = new Contact();
            cnt.FirstName = ld.FirstName;
            cnt.LastName = ld.LastName;
            cnt.Email = ld.Email;
            conInsertList.add(cnt);
        }
        //code to create contacts for parent and student if form is filled by parent
        else {
            if (ld.Email != cemail && ld.Parent_or_guardian__c == true) {
                Contact cnt1 = new Contact();
                cnt1.RecordTypeId = recordtype2;
                cnt1.FirstName = ld.Parent_First_Name__c;
                cnt1.LastName = ld.Parent_Last_Name__c;
                cnt1.Email = ld.Parent_Email__c;
                conInsertList.add(cnt1);
                Contact cnt2 = new Contact();
                cnt2.RecordTypeId = recordtype1;
                cnt2.FirstName = ld.FirstName;
                cnt2.LastName = ld.LastName;
                cnt2.Email = ld.Email;
                conInsertList.add(cnt2);
            }
        }
    }
    if (conInsertList.size() > 0) {
        INSERT conInsertList;
        List < Id > conInsert = new List < Id > ();
        //catch the inserted contact ids to create relationship record
        if (conInsertList.size() > 1) {
            for (Integer i = 0, s = conInsertList.size(); i < s; i += 2) {
                //creates relation record by catching current student and parent record id's
                hed__Relationship__c hedrel = new hed__Relationship__c();
                hedrel.hed__Contact__c = conInsertList[i + 1].Id;
                hedrel.hed__RelatedContact__c = conInsertList[i].Id;
                hedrel.hed__Type__c = 'Parent';
                relation.add(hedrel);
                //creates affiliation record if filled by parent
                if (listname.isEmpty() == false && record != null) {
                    hed__Affiliation__c hedaff = new hed__Affiliation__c();
                    hedaff.hed__Account__c = record;
                    hedaff.hed__Contact__c = conInsertList[i + 1].Id;
                    hedaff.hed__Primary__c = true;
                    affiliation.add(hedaff);
                }
                //creates affiliation records for other programs multi select picklist field
                if (otherProgramsValueSet != null) {
                    Map < String, Id > accNamesToIdsMap = new Map < String, Id > ();
                    for (Account acc: [select id, Pardot_Program_Name__c from account where Pardot_Program_Name__c in: otherProgramsValueSet]) {
                        accNamesToIdsMap.put(acc.Pardot_Program_Name__c, acc.Id);
                    }
                    for (Id accId: accNamesToIdsMap.values()) {
                        affiliationListToBeInserted.add(new hed__Affiliation__c(hed__Account__c = accId,
                            hed__Contact__c = conInsertList[i + 1].Id));
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            //creates Affiliation record if filled by student only
            if (conInsertList.size() == 1) {
                for (Integer i = 0, s = conInsertList.size(); i < s; i += 2) {
                    if (listname.isEmpty() == false && record != null) {
                        hed__Affiliation__c hedaff = new hed__Affiliation__c();
                        hedaff.hed__Account__c = record;
                        hedaff.hed__Contact__c = conInsertList[i].Id;
                        hedaff.hed__Primary__c = true;
                        affiliation.add(hedaff);
                    }
                    if (otherProgramsValueSet != null) {
                        Map < String, Id > accNamesToIdsMap = new Map < String, Id > ();
                        for (Account acc: [select id, Pardot_Program_Name__c from account where Pardot_Program_Name__c in: otherProgramsValueSet]) {
                            accNamesToIdsMap.put(acc.Pardot_Program_Name__c, acc.Id);
                        }
                        for (Id accId: accNamesToIdsMap.values()) {
                            affiliationListToBeInserted.add(new hed__Affiliation__c(hed__Account__c = accId, hed__Contact__c = conInsertList[i].Id));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        insert relation;
        insert affiliation;
        insert affiliationListToBeInserted;
    }

    LeadStatus convertStatus = [Select MasterLabel from LeadStatus where IsConverted = true limit 1];

    List < Database.LeadConvert > leadConverts = new List < Database.LeadConvert > ();
    map < Id, Contact > conMap = new map < Id, Contact > ();
    for (Lead lead: Trigger.new) {
        if (!lead.isConverted && lead.Status == 'New') {
            Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
            String opportunityName = lead.Name;

            lc.setLeadId(lead.Id);
            lc.setSendNotificationEmail(false);
            lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
            String currentemail = lead.Email;
            List < Contact > id1 = [SELECT Id, Email, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Email =: currentemail AND recordtype.name = 'Lead'];
            String Idcon;
            string accname123;
            for (Contact ce1: id1) {
                Idcon = ce1.Id;
                accname123 = ce1.AccountId;
            }
            lc.setContactId(Idcon);
            lc.setAccountId(accname123);
            lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
            leadConverts.add(lc);
        }
    }
    if (!leadConverts.isEmpty()) {
        List < Database.LeadConvertResult > lcr = Database.convertLead(leadConverts);
    }
}
```

Comment: Including the stack trace (which tells you the line number), and doing something to point out where that line is in your code will be helpful. A brief glance makes me think that this is an issue with the two lines of code where you access `someList[i+1]` inside of a loop that increments i by 2. Can you explain why those loops are being incremented by 2 instead of 1?

Comment: hello @DerekF, on lead I will be having two sections one is for student details and other is parent, so if Parent_or_guardian__c field is true then I need to create two contacts then I need to catch those two contacts and then creates relationship records for those two contacts in hed_Relationship object, on relationship object, in hed__Contact__c  field I need to populate student contact Id then on hed__RelatedContact__c  i need to pass parent contact Id

Comment: hello @DerekF,Actually, On lead object I have two sections Student detail(Standard lead Fields) and parent details(create custom field like Fname, Lname and Email).
So once Parent_or_guardian__c = true then I need to create two Contacts for student and parent, then I need to catch those two contact ids then create a record in hed_Relationship object where hed__Contact__c = studentcontactId and hed__RelatedContact__c = parent Id so I used for loop.
If lead contains only student section is filled then no need to create relationship record.
Can you please help me out in this issue if possible.

Comment: so to catch those contact id's I created that loop

Comment: @Lakshmi Please [edit] your post to add all of these details.

Comment: @DavidReed, I did mention all the details now, can you help me out in this issue if possible please.