# apex trigger throwing error Expression must be a list type: Set<Id>

Tags: apex, trigger

when I am saving the below trigger then I am getting the following error, can anyone help me out in this issue at line `hedrel.hed__Contact__c = conIds[0] ;`

> Expression must be a list type:    Set

```
    if(conInsertList.size()>0){
    INSERT conInsertList;
    Set<Id> conIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Contact acc : conInsertList){
     conIds.add(acc.id);
             }
    //catch the inserted contact ids to create relationship record
    if(conInsertList.size()>1){
        //creates relation record by catching current student and parent record id's
        hed__Relationship__c hedrel = new hed__Relationship__c();
        hedrel.hed__Contact__c = conIds[0] ;
        hedrel.hed__RelatedContact__c = conIds[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

`Set` is an un-ordered collection i.e. it can have elements in any order, hence you cannot access the elements in `set` using the `index`.

Excerpt from salesforce documentation of [Set](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_sets.htm)

> A set is an unordered collection of elements that do not contain any
>   duplicates. Set elements can be of any data type—primitive types,
>   collections, sObjects, user-defined types, and built-in Apex types.

So, if you wan't to access the elements in collection using `index`, you should instead use [List](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm), but problem with `List` is that it can contain duplicate values, so you will have to handle those scenarios as well.

To avoid duplicates in `List`, you can use `contains` method of `List`

```
List<Id> conIds = new List<Id>();
for(Contact acc : conInsertList){
    if(!conIds.contains(acc.id)){
        conIds.add(acc.id);
    }
}
```

And then you can use

```
hedrel.hed__Contact__c = conIds[0] ;
hedrel.hed__RelatedContact__c = conIds[1];
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can continue using a set, and then pass that set into the constructor for a list `List<Id> conIdList = new List<Id>(conIdSet);` Saves a bit of typing, and possibly saves a (usually insignificant) amount of cpu time.

Comment: Yes @DerekF, I thought of including that but am not sure if the sequencing would be maintained in that case.

Comment: @VijayGanji, will it work if I bulk insert leads?

Comment: @sainath As far as the code mentioned in the question is concerned, it should ideally work even for bulk insert. I am not sure about the logic of your code, but only additional check you will need is `if(conInsertList.size()>1 && conIds.size()>1)` before creating a relationship record.

Comment: @VijayGanji, what I am doing is,Actually, On lead object I have two sections Student details(Standard lead Fields) and parent details(created custom field like Fname, Lname and Email).

So once Parent_or_guardian__c = true then I need to create two Contacts for student and parent, then I need to catch those two contact ids then create a record in hed_Relationship object where hed__Contact__c = studentcontactId and hed__RelatedContact__c = parent Id so I used for loop.
If lead contains only student section is filled then no need to create relationship record.

Comment: @VijayGanji with the code you suggested, its creating relationship record for all the leads that I have inserted, I am adding y whole code into question.

Comment: @sainath Unless the code to create relationship is in `for loop`, it should not create multiple records. I would suggest you to post a separate question for that and include the relevant code along with it. SFSE members normally follow a single question per post pattern and that is how you can make best out of this platform.

Comment: @VijayGanji, can you please refer this link [Link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271037/lead-conversion-trigger-causing-issue-when-multiple-lead-records-are-inserted)